# Bootstrap 4 Using card class inside d-flex

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using the d-flex class for 4 cards I want to align side by side, I am using the following markup:

```
<div id="home">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-between"> 
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-title">Card 1</div>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
            <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-title">Card 2</div>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
            <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-title">Card 3</div>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
            <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-title">Card 4</div>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
            <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

Each card is taking the entire width of the view and stacking vertically.  Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Each card is taking the entire width of the view and stacking vertically. Is there something that I am missing?"

That's happening because of the `flex-wrap` class in the `d-flex`. Removing it allows the cards to evenly fill the row.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between"> 
        <div class="card">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Oxqz1ZI5xT

Comment: Ok, removed the flex-wrap but now the cards are resized on smaller devices instead of wrapping.

Comment: Yes, that's the intended behavior. Use the grid columns if you want different responsive behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Zim.  Guess it's back to the column classes.  Still learning Bootstrap so I appreciate the patience.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the "flex-wrap" class from the second div.